# como mudar a orientação do dompdf

Tags: php, dompdf

como mudar a orientação do dompdf.
Já incluir o seguinte codigo, mas não funcionou

```
$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');
```

Comment: Esse é o código correto. O que está acontecendo? Ele não muda a orientação? Ele gera algum erro?

Comment: descobri o que era, a posição do codigo. tinha coloca como abaixo, mas tem que ser invertido para funcionar.
 $dompdf->render();
 $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape');

Comment: Entendi! Legal!

Answer (score -1):

Caso eu tenha entendido e seja mesmo problema que passei

- $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');  //Retrato
- $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'landscape'); //Paisagem

Comment: Poderia ajustar o seu código para melhor visualização? Aqui utilizamos o markdown.